# nginx proxy_pass two ports into subfolders

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, websocket

So I had my last "reverse proxy" problem fixed regarding "mapping" a port to a subfolder Thanks again to this awesome community.

I have been able to work with this solution for a while but now I am facing a new problem. The situation is:

There is a webpage setup (using nginx) with this url `http://test.domain.com:8042/view.html`. I needed for various reasons that this port turns into a subfolder and achieved it (with help) and gained `http://test.domain.com/view/view.html`.

The proxy_pass for this is:

```
location ~/view(.*)$ {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_pass http://test.domain.com:8042$1;
```

This works amazing. I can access the page over `http://test.domain.com/view/view.html`. There are several websockets on that page, one also has the port 8042. This one works fine. However, the other websockets have different ports, e.g. 8159. I have added an respective proxy_pass to the nginx config:

```
location ~/cantrace(.*)$ {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_pass http://test.domain.com:8159$1;
```

From Javascript this websocket is called via

```
my_websocket = new WebSocket('ws://test.domain.com/cantrace/ws');
```

but that does not work. Neither does

```
my_websocket = new WebSocket('ws://test.domain.com/view/cantrace/ws');
```

What does work, however, is

```
http://test.domain.com:8042/view.html
```

and then it loads the other websockets on view.html with

```
my_websocket = new WebSocket('ws://test.domain.com/cantrace/ws');
```

which did previously not work.

So clearly the double proxy_pass with /view and /cantrace is a problem here. Is there a way to work around this with nginx?

Thank you very much!

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I had such a setup to access two servers behind a reverse proxy, I believe your `proxy_passs` directive is missing a trailing `/`, this was my setup:

```
       location /server1 {
               proxy_pass http://server1:8081/;
               proxy_buffering off;
       }
       location /server2 {
               proxy_pass http://server2:8082/;
               proxy_buffering off;
       }
```

In your case, this would translate to:

```
proxy_pass http://test.domain.com:8042/$1;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Unfortunately that did not really work although I believe it should have. However, this would resolve to http://test.domain.com:8042/cantrace but I also want to get rid of the first port number. I am starting to believe nginx can't do that and I should fall back to solutions outside of nginx.